# MongoDB Compass can't insert document by pasting json string

Tags: mongodb, compass

I'm using compass community v1.13.1 and have been trying to populate some sample data for couple of hours, but failed.

Found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692141/mongodb-compass-visually-insert-sub-document), I followed the first answer by @ktsangop but it didn't work.

Cant paste as a json object anyway, if I set type to string, it will be just blank string; if set type to object, can't paste the json string as a whole.
[image]

Do I need to insert a valid json object one field by one field? or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: according to compass's doc, we should be able to paste json object.  https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/#insert-documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't believe that this is an actual issue.. for the first 2 minutes I though that something is wrong with me lol

Anyhow, I do have a (hacky) solution:

1. Select an item and click the `Edit Document` button
2. Create a new field or select existing one for editing
3. Enter a double-quote sign `"`
4. Copy the json payload
5. Seek to the beginning of the field and remove the double-quote sign (in step 3)
6. Save document changes

TADA!

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems like the copy-paste action will only take effect if the json is partial (valid jsons are ignored for some reason).. so I ended-up with an easier solution:

1. Select an item and click the `Edit Document` button
2. Create a new field or select existing one for editing
3. Omit the last character from your json payload (for `{ "a": true }` copy only `{ "a": true`)
4. Copy the partial json payload
5. Seek to the end of the field add the missing character (in our sample `}`)
6. Save document changes

Comment: Thanks this workaround works, but what a lack of ergonomy. Incredible that we can't edit document in plain text!

Comment: Don't need to omit the last curly bracket, just only indent one space is enough.

Answer (score 2):

*For future visitors*: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65298615/1454261) answer might help.

Just switch the view to JSON (the two curlies button - a feature that was added after this question was raised it seems like), hit "Edit Document" upon hovering a document, and then you will be editing the JSON directly which gives you a lot of flexibility and speed.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But MongoDB Compass has still by far the worst user experience of all apps that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting a new document manually in MongoDB compass by following steps:

1. Create a document and insert a new property:

[image: for creating a document and inserting new property]

2. Add a new property inside the object:

[image: inside the object adding new property]

3. Change the type of document property:

[image: change the type of document property]

4. Final document is ready to insert:

[image: final document is ready to insert]

Answer (score 0):

You need to Expand All than you can change type to object.